# Minecraft - How To See Scoreboards

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I set up my scoreboard with:

```
/scoreboard objectives add Deaths deathCount Deaths
```

Then I did:

```
/scoreboard objectives setDisplay list Deaths
```

I can't see the scoreboard though! If I do the right command it will tell me, but I can't actually see the scoreboard. If anyone could help me fix this, please tell me!

Comment: You set a scoreboard with two names: A display name and a name that you use to refer to it when executing commands. when using `setDisplay` might you be referring to the display name to try and see the scoreboard?

Comment: All I know is that I want to be able to see the scoreboard

Comment: You need to tell me these things so I can know what could be wrong. You need to help me help you.

Comment: OK. I'll go add all that I did in the question.

Answer (score 7):

The scoreboard will not display because `Deaths` has not been triggered yet.

Simply trigger the objective by a) dying or b) changing the value of the objective with commands. Type `/scoreboard players set [player] Deaths 1` then `/scoreboard players set [player] Deaths 0`

EDIT: @lennartVH01 pointed out that you may be looking in the wrong place for the scoreboard. The `list` display type is displayed when you press `TAB`, whereas `sidebar` displays on the side of the screen. Also, `belowName` displays under the name of a player.

Comment: It does not have to be more than 1 to show. The scoreboard is basically an table. The event has to trigger for the name to be added into the table. Simply put, **you can either cause the event to trigger once** (basically you need to die), thus updating the table with the new player or **you can manually input an entry of whatever value into the table** (executing command stated above whose value need not be 1)

Comment: I did but it still didn't show.

Comment: you do know that the `list` slot is the tab menu, and `sidebar` is a table on the right side of the screen

Comment: @DarkDestry That makes sense. I will add it to my answer.

Comment: you could just do /scoreboard players set [player] Deaths 0 that would work too

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do

```
/scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar Deaths
```